# Splitting a Symfony 2 project?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, domain-driven-design, decoupling

We have a pretty large Symfony 2 web application which has many different endpoints and features:

- api for data from our legacy product
- web components for use in our legacy product
- api to our new iOS POS
- api to loyalty end-user portal
- web interface for loyalty end-user portal
- web interface for (seperate) invoice end-user portal
- big admin area with configuration for all of the above

The database layer (in Doctrine) on this is tightly coupled. Transactions from both the POS and our legacy product are used in the loyalty end-user portals and invoices are based on the same transactions. Obviously there's also many entities that are solely for specific parts of the application.

We originally decided on the single app+bundle approach for ease of programming, which has served us well in developing the whole platform. Unfortunately the main drawbacks are:

- very bad performance (although things like further caching, minimizing assets etc can help, we think that having such a bloated bundle that needs to be able to handle everything and also included different 3rd-party libraries only used in specific parts of the application is slowing everything down.)
- we use continuous integration and generating new builds and running all the functional tests is taking 20+ minutes.. and we still have many classes lacking (proper) tests.
- when we change part of the application, another part breaks easily. Although more and more decoupling and functional tests help with that, it's still far from ideal.

I've done some research to splitting a Symfony project into multiple projects (each with it's own github) and using SOA to connect them. My personal experience so far with SOA is that it makes things very hard to test fully and adds lots of overhead when migrating from standard Symfony 2 forms (which I totally love).

I was also thinking on another solution by creating a shared bundle with the shared entities and repositories. This would make it much easier to test code and share common services (managers), although I've also heard argumentation against big managers. The big downside to this is that we cannot simply use doctrine:schema:update then, because sharing the database and updating the database on a project with a lower version of the shared bundle, will remove fields.. causing loss of data. Also on this approach I have been unable to find any examples or use-cases.. which leads me to wonder if it wouldn't have many more downsides.

So my question is: what are common approaches and solutions for splitting a big project like this? And: are there reasons that maybe it should not be split at all?

Comment: With respect to performance, do some profiling to see where the bottle necks are.  A big application does not necessarily slow things down since each request/response is only going to load what it needs.  Don't waste time guessing about optimization.

Comment: Performance is actually only a side-issue for this change. The biggest reason to split the project is to reduce inter-dependancy (forcing decoupling) and make it easier to upgrade or add apps. It's also more logical as different (critical) processes are for different end-users and organisations.

Answer (score 3):

*Although I'm answering your question, It's kinda hard to come with a magical solution for your problems. This is not an attempt to solve all of your problems, nor impose you of following it. This is not the only possible solution, actually this might not even solve your problems. That said, let's begin.*

I'd split the project in 4 layers:

- **Presentation Layer:** Desktop aplications, Web interfaces (no matter if
  is php, C#, if it uses Symphony or any other framework and third
  library components), Mobile Apps, everything end users can see and
  interact with (also known as GUI). These guys only communicate with
  Application/Service to request something, like a list of available
  products, update some data somewhere, send an e-mail for customers.
  The key here is they really don't know how and where is
  Appication/Service layer going to do the requested actions.
- **Application/Service Layer:** I'd treat this as *controllers* which can    receive requests from the Presentation Layer, and external webservices as well. They look like APIs, and will *decide* if they have to access/manipulate data through a [Repository](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx), or send e-mails using some SMPT service. They just makes the communication between GUI or external webservices which might consume your APIs and Domain/Infra layers. Yet they don't actually know what SMPT service they are using, or where data is going to be stored and how (in a MySql through Doctrine? in Sql Server through Entity Framework? in a NoSql database? txt files?). Application layers usually have their own Models (also known as ViewModels), which are exposed to the world and returned to the requester (GUI or external Webservice), representing **part of** the domain models. This mapping (convert Domain classes to Application classes) can be done with patterns like Facade and Adapters (also called the Anti-corruption layer), and there are plenty of packages to resolve this (for C#, there is Automapper, for PHP there might exist something either). Why should you need this? To avoid exposing your full domain to the world. Suppose you have Invoice and Loyalty end-users, but you wanna treat them as one unique domain class "User" with their corresponding properties together. You could create a LoyaltyUser and an InvoiceUser classes in your application, each one containing only the necessary properties for that purpose, then use this Mapping technique to map the domain User class to each one of them. Therefore, the application layer usually contains authentication and authorization rules, so only the Loyalty end-user would have permission to access controller's actions which would deal with the LoyaltyUser model. Inside a single action in a controller, you shouldn't take     different paths/ways depending on the requester (for mobile, do this, for website, do that). Instead, you might have different actions for each one, and tue Presentation layer knows what they want to request.
- **Domain Layer:** This is your core, containing all business logic. This is what provide value to your business. Domain layer container
  models/classes representing real entities from your world, interfaces
  for services and repositories. Domain must be the most clean and
  natural possible. They can't know what application is asking
  something, nor how type of infra is being used. They just do business
  logic. The Domain layer don't know if your are using Doctrine or Laravel as an ORM, nor if the application is a php website done with Symphony, or an Android Native App.
- **Infra Layer:** Here you implement things like database, SMPT service, Logging, and other things your application might need.
  Doctrine would reside here. Therefore, you would create Repository
  classes implementing the repository interfaces of your domain. The
  Repository implementation uses Doctrine to do stuff. These
  implementations are providen to Application Layer (normally via
  Dependency Injection). This means the Application Layer shouldn't
  know if is Doctrine or Laravel, that's why the Application uses the
  Repository (so logic to access database are encapsulated).

Your web interfaces would reside in Presentation. If the framework you use in your web have to use MVC and therefore have controllers, these controllers should dispatch to the Application Layer (I know it sounds redundant). Your APIs would reside in Application Layer.

This is very decoupled, if you need to change from Doctrine to Laravel, your don't need to change your Domain nor your Apps. If your need to change from Symphony to anything else, or even change your website from PHP to ASP or Java, your domain don't have to be changed.

Adding more layers, mapping objects, using DI shouldn't make requests slower, considering the hardware's price and capacity nowadays, the difference in time is almost imperceptible. You should put efforts attempting to improve your domain, which brings value for the business. Separating layers improve decoupling, chances of changing part of application breaking other parts, increase flexibility of scaling your app, and makes testing easier.

Answer (score 0):

Rein, what was the solution you've finally ended up with? Have you actually split your project?

There is really a lack of information in this area, I just found one reasonable article https://ig.nore.me/presentations/2015/04/splitting-a-symfony-project-into-separate-tiers/